# ASP.NET: How can I pass standard information between Masters/Pages in the code-behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop, inheritance, master-pages

I need my child pages to be able to set the values of certain properties of the Master page *before* loading.

In other words, *how* my application builds the Master page for the client depends upon what properties are set by the child pages on the back-end.

For example:

```
public partial class mstrPage : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    public int Rows { get; set; }
    public int Cols { get; set; }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        /* Build a .NET two-dimensional-array of divs
             that is <Rows> tall and <Cols> wide. */
    }
}
```

In this example, the child page needs to set the values of `<Rows>` and `<Cols>` before `Page_Load()` is invoked for the Master.

This is fairly simple to accomplish with inheritance in OOP, but ASP.NET web pages do not "inherit" their master pages in the code-behind.

In the given example, what would the code-behind look like for the ASP.NET child page that sets these properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple... on the master page at the top, set the directive:

```
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/MASTERPAGEFILE.master" %>
```

in the child content pages you can access the properties by typing: `Master.PROPERTYNAME`

See: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228274.aspx)

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!